# How to transfer one domain to another domain without losing theme options (customizer)?

Tags: theme-development, customization, database, theme-customizer, migration

I have developed the one wordpress site with custom theme,

Here I used the custom customizer options.

Then site completed on my local machine I mean localhost `(http://127.0.0.1/wordpress)`.

Now the problem is I tried to transfer my site to live domain `(http://wordpress.bla.com)`.

***How I tried to transfer files?***

1) exported the database from localhost/phpmyadmin and changed the oldurl to new url using `ctrl+f`.

2) then transfered files through ftp.

After live site opens without logo, header menu, and custom customizer data. but `DB` having these values.

***What I expect from you guys?***

*How to avoid these losing theme options?*

I tried many times and checked all the old url was changed to new url in DB.

But I didn't get theme options values in new url.

please suggest me to  *avoid these losing theme options?*

Thanks.

Comment: If you get broken links see what urls are trying to load. This will give you a better idea of what needs to be search/replaced in your target deploy.

Comment: I didn't get any broken link.

Comment: I think serialized data not returning properly after replacing new url.

Comment: You might have corrupt DB entries then. Try a clean seacrh replace using a tool like wp-cli or https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: sorry unfortunately Its not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not replace the URL in the database using ctrl+f or any other "direct" method. You have to do a search & replace in the whole database in a way capable of **keeping the validity of serialized data**.

There are several tools to do that serialized seach & replace. For example:

1. Plugins like [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/), [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) or [All-in-One WP Migration](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/).
2. [WP-CLI's search-replace](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/)
3. [Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: thanks. I tried 3rd but it not working for me. i will try remaining

Comment: I've used all of them with sucess; most often second and third. The plugin I know more is All-in-one WP Migration. You may be not using it well.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is not *what tool to use*; the answer is **do the search&replace in the whole database and keeping validity of serialized data**. The suggested tools are just that, suggestions.